# login password issue

Tags: keyboard, login, layout

i have a very strange problem.
It looks like my keyboard layout is always changing when i try to login my Ubuntu installation.
My password contains the character @
So the problem is that one time the @ symbol is produced by pressing shift+2 keys and some other time i will have to press shift+" that is two positions right of L key.

If during my work i let it inactive for some minutes and then let the OS lock the screen, then, even i haven't restarted the laptop, some times even forgets the combination that worked some minutes ago and i will always have to try these two combinations to login.

This also happens on the terminal when i ask for sudo permissions.

I really hate this small problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to **System Settings -> Text Entry** and remove all additional input sources from the **Input Sources to Use** box.

Comment: hi,thanks for the reply. The problem is that i need this extra Greek source keyboard for my communication. It didnt use to confuse the both of them. It started after my last installation of Ubuntu on a clean laptop. Thanks